# Polkadot websocket API doesn't emits changes in stats like system_health or system_syncState

Tags: polkadot, golang

using the following code ,

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"github.com/gorilla/websocket"
"log"
)

type Message struct {
Id      int         `json:"id"`
Jsonrpc string      `json:"jsonrpc"`
Method  string      `json:"method"`
Params  interface{} `json:"params"`
}

func main() {
// create a new WebSocket connection to the Polkadot node
endpoint := fmt.Sprintf("ws://%s:%d", "localhost", 9944)
conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(endpoint, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dial:", err)
}
defer conn.Close()

// subscribe to new block headers
message := Message{
    Id:      1,
    Jsonrpc: "2.0",
    Method:  "system_health",
    Params:  []interface{}{},
}
err = conn.WriteJSON(message)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("write:", err)
}

// listen for new peers
for {
    _, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("read:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("New message: %s\n", message)
    // Do something with the new message
}
}
```

i get this response only once

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result{"peers":32,"isSyncing":true,"shouldHavePeers":true},"id":1}
```

and the the code blocks here : conn.ReadMessage()

however i expected it will stream the changes every time the peers count changes or isSyncing changes for example

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result{"peers":32,"isSyncing":true,"shouldHavePeers":true},"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result{"peers":33,"isSyncing":true,"shouldHavePeers":true},"id":1}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result{"peers":34,"isSyncing":true,"shouldHavePeers":true},"id":1}
```

and so one.

am i missing something here ?